# This spams dms how do I make it stop after one message Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('AC0');
    client.user.setActivity('Tornaments', { type: 'WATCHING'}).catch(console.error);
});
    const tornament = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#000ff')
        .setTitle('AC0 Tornaments')
        .setDescription(`1. TORNAMENT1
                 2. TORNAMENT2
                 3. TORNAMENT3
                 4. TORNAMENT4`)
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.id === '694644198531661844') {
        if (message.content === '>endac0') {
            process.exit();
}}
        if (message.content === '>tornaments') {
            message.channel.send(tornament);
}
        if (message.content.startsWith('>tornamentsadd')){
            client.users.fetch('694644198531661844').then(user => {
                user.send(`${message.content.toString()}`)
                

            
});}

});

client.login('')
```

How would I make it not spam me I don't think there is a loop or anything in it also I don't know what else to add so yeah I will just keep typing

Comment: You probably have a loop outside of that if statement. Could you show us your whole script? (make sure to remove your discord bot key thing aswell)

Comment: I put all the code

Comment: I took out the message to string and replaced it with some text and it doesn't spam me the problem is with the message to string

Comment: I also tried as user.send(`${message.content}`)  that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add a return function at the end.

```
if (message.content.startsWith('>tornamentsadd')){
            client.users.fetch('694644198531661844').then(user => {
               return user.send(`${message.content.toString()}`)
```